# Amazon RDS PHP MSSQL

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, rds, dlib

I'm trying to open a connection to `Amazon RDS MS-SQL` from Hosting with `MSSQL` library with following code:

```
<?php
$dbhost  = "xxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com";
$dbport  = 1433;
$dbname  = "xxxxx";
$dbuser  = "xxxxxx";
$dbpass  = "xxxxxxx";
try {
    $dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$dbhost:$dbport;dbname=$dbname","$dbuser","$dbpass");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
}
```

and I am getting this error:

```
Failed to get DB handle: SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)
```

Comment: you need to allow your ip to connect to the database from an external program

Comment: `$dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$dbhost;$dbport;dbname=$dbname","$dbuser","$dbpass");` replace this line and try

Comment: I can get you, that  are the same code. And if you know RDS service you can't get the ip.

Comment: Is the PHP server running outside of AWS? If so you need to enable the "publicly accessible" flag on your RDS instance. You also need to open the Security Group assigned to the RDS instance to allow incoming traffic from the PHP server.